# Query to compare 3 different data columns with a reference value

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to check whether a table (in an Oracle DB) contains entries that were updated after a certain date. "Updated" in this case means any of 3 columns (`DateCreated`, `DateModified`, `DateDeleted`) have a value greater than the reference.
The query I have come up so far is this

```
select * from myTable
where DateCreated  > :reference_date
   or DateModified > :reference_date
   or DateDeleted  > :reference_date
;
```

This works and gives desired results, but is not what I want, because I would like to enter the value for `:reference_date` only once.
Any ideas on how I could write a more elegant query ?

Comment: But this *is* once. You have *one* bind variable named reference_date that you use three times in your query.

Comment: Using Oracle, if you do DESCRIBE INPUT (or similar), do you get count = 1 or 3 in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While what you have looks fine and only uses one bind variable, if for some reason you have positional rather than named binds then you *could* avoid the need to supply the bind value multiple time by using an inline view or a CTE:

```
with cte as (select :reference_date as reference_date from dual)
select myTable.*
from cte
join myTable
on myTable.DateCreated  > cte.reference_date
   or myTable.DateModified > cte.reference_date
   or myTable.DateDeleted  > cte.reference_date
;
```

But again I wouldn't consider that better than your original unless you have a really compelling reason and a problem supplying the bind value. Having to set it three times from a calling program probably wouldn't count as compelling, for example, for me anyway. And I'd check it didn't affect performance before deploying - I'd expect Oracle to optimise something like this but the execution plan might be interesting.

Comment: Nice, this is just what I was looking for. I have compared the execution plans and your solution has a cost of 5 (compared to 4 for mine). The slight performance decrease is not problematic and this will result in much cleaner code in my calling program (where I have to use positional parameters indeed).

Answer (score 0):

I *suppose* you could rewrite that as:

```
select * from myTable
where greatest(DateCreated, DateModified, DateDeleted)  > :reference_date;
```

if you absolutely had to, but I wouldn't. Your original query is, IMHO, much easier to understand than this one, plus by using a function, you've lost any chance of using an index, should one exist (unless you have a function based index based on the new clause).

Comment: I agree; this is a solution, but the original query is preferable. And: GREATEST returns NULL, when any value is NULL. So you will have to combine this with COALESCE which makes this even more complicated and less readable.

Comment: Good point! Although I'd use nvls around each column instead (it's shorter than coalesce!).

ETA: in fact, to make the nvl'd default value to either match or not match the condition (depending on requirements), I'd tie it to the :reference_date anyway (eg. nvl(datecreated, :reference_date-1)), which would kinda negate the whole point of using greatest in the first place!

Comment: You could use `GREATEST(NVL(DateCreated, DATE'0001-01-01'), NVL(DateModified, DATE'0001-01-01'), NVL(DateDeleted, DATE'0001-01-01'))` or even `GREATEST(COALESCE(DateCreated, DateModified, DateDeleted), COALESCE(DateDeleted,DateCreated, DateModified), COALESCE(DateModified,DateDeleted,DateCreated))`.